# Почему PHP не предоставляет ресурсы веб-сайта клиентам?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

При работе веб-приложения через PHP оказалось, что вместо любых ресурсов PHP отправляет HTML разметку `index.php`. Из-за этого клиенты не получают ни каскадных таблиц стилей, ни изображений.

**Вопрос:** Как мне заставить PHP отправлять клиентам ресурсы (изображения, каскадные таблицы стилей и так далее)?

## Пример

### `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="edit.png">Nope! Again>:!</img>
        <? echo '<img src="edit.png">Nope! Again>:!</img>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

### `edit.png`

Изображение `edit.png` находится везде. И в корневой папке веб-приложения, и во всех его подпапках, и во всех подпапках самого PHP. **Ошибок с путями быть не может и не нужно об этом писать.**

### Результат

[image: Browser network tracking]

1. Клиент переходит на веб-сайт.
2. Веб-обозреватель получает HTML разметку веб-сайта.
3. В разметке веб-обозреватель видит дополнительный ресурс - изображение `edit.png`.
4. Веб-обозреватель запрашивает дополнительный ресурс, указывая, что в ответ он ожидает изображение.
5. PHP отправляет не запрашиваемое изображение, а HTML разметку `index.php`.

Последний пункт я проверил при помощи команды `curl.exe http://localhost:22833/edit.png -o response`.

### PHP

Я уверен, что PHP (при помощи параметра `-t`) запускается именно из корневой папки веб-приложения.

Результат идентичен на версиях `ts 8.0.11` и `ts 7.2.24`.

Примечание: На другом компьютере у меня есть полная копия моей версии `ts 7.2.24`. С ней у меня не возникало подобных проблем. Впрочем, проверить приведенный пример на нем я сейчас не могу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130266/discussion-on-question-by-shamus-rezol--php-----).

Comment: Я надеюсь, получилось разобраться?